# Select top 10 values set in clause where using procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using a procedure with parameters : @TOP & @Bottom, which means when I type for example 50 in `@TOP`, sql must brings me top 50 sales

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELL] @TOP int, @BOTTOM int AS

SELECT E_REGION, E_LIBELLE, SUM(E_MONTANTTTC) as TOTAL VENTE,

FROM SALE

GROUP BY    
    e_region, e_LIBELLE

     ORDER BY  e_region, e_MONTANTTTC desc

 EXEC [SELL] @TOP='', @BOTTOM='';
```

Please how to get N top sales when typing N in the parameter @TOP.
Ex : When : @top=20 
Then the query returns top 20 sales (e_MONTANTTTC)

Comment: Hint:  `TOP @TOP`

Comment: What's `@Bottom` supposed to do?

Comment: @bottom it's the opposite of TOP

Comment: To use 'bottom' (least *N* elements) you coud use TOP with *ASC* order. Also spaces are not allowed in column names: use delimiters `[TOTAL VENTE]` or underscores `TOTAL_VENTE` the latter is better choice

Comment: So if you do `EXEC [SELL] @TOP=10, @BOTTOM=5;` what should the result be?

Comment: IF i use a value in TOP, i let bottom empty, i can't use 2 value in the same time

Answer (score 0):

in sql server you can use ofset fetch next

```
select *
from tabla
order by 1
offset 0 rows fetch next 50 rows only;
```

offset is when you start and fetch next registers numbers, if you want the first 50, you offset is 0 and your fetch next is 50 like in example.

Comment: It's worth noting that `offset...fetch` was introduced in 2012 version. 2008 is sadly still used today, even though it's extended support is about to end this year (if memory serves)

Comment: So i can use : offset 0 rows fetch next 50 rows only in the where clause ?

Comment: you can use a variable   declare @a int = 1

select *
from tabla
order by 1
offset 0 rows fetch next @a rows only;

Comment: I didn't know where to place this code, inside the where clause ? so i can make a condition like : @top = offset 0 rows fetch next 50 rows only ??

Comment: just replace 50 for @TOP

Answer (score 0):

Following the conversation in the comments, What you are looking for can be done with conditional sorting and `top`. I've modified your current procedure and added comments inside to make it (hopefully) easy to understand what I've done:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELL] 
(
    @TOP int, 
    @BOTTOM int 
)
AS
-- if both top and bottom have values, do nothing
IF @TOP IS NULL OR @BOTTOM IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- ABS: if @top or @bottom have a negative value, handle it as if it was positive
    -- COELASCE: if both @top and @bottom are null, get 0 rows back.
    SELECT TOP (ABS(COELASCE(@TOP, @BOTTOM, 0))) E_REGION, E_LIBELLE, SUM(E_MONTANTTTC) as TOTAL VENTE
    FROM SALE
    GROUP BY e_region, e_LIBELLE
    -- IIF: returns the second argument if the condition in the first argument is true, else the third argument
    ORDER BY IIF(@TOP IS NOT NULL, e_region, NULL), 
             IIF(@BOTTOM NOT IS NULL, e_region, NULL) DESC,
             IIF(@TOP IS NOT NULL, e_MONTANTTTC, NULL) DESC, 
             IIF(@BOTTOM IS NOT NULL, e_MONTANTTTC, NULL) 
END
```

However, I think it would make more sense to not use the mutually exclusive `@top` and `@bottom` parameters, but it use one parameter to set the number of rows returned, and one parameter to determine the sort order - so I've also written this version for you (basically, changed very little from the first version, and removed the comments):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELL] 
(
    @COUNT int, 
    @ASC bit 
)
AS

SELECT TOP (ABS(ISNULL(@COUNT, 0))) E_REGION, E_LIBELLE, SUM(E_MONTANTTTC) as TOTAL VENTE
FROM SALE
GROUP BY e_region, e_LIBELLE
ORDER BY IIF(@ASC = 1, e_region, NULL), 
         IIF(ISNULL(@ASC, 0) = 0, e_region, NULL) DESC,
         IIF(@ASC = 1, e_MONTANTTTC, NULL) DESC, 
         IIF(ISNULL(@ASC, 0) = 0, e_MONTANTTTC, NULL)
```

Comment: Thank's for your comment, i get an error message : IFF is not recognized built-in function name. I'm using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: @HamzaSoufiane `IIF` was introduced in 2012. It's a short hand way of writing `case when...else...end`. I've edited my answer with a `case...when` on the first example - I'm sure you can do the same for the second example.